# Sort large amount of data before inserting to database

Tags: android, json, sqlite, gson, greendao

I need to download a large json String. I'm using aQuery for this. Then I need to parse this string in a list of objects (10k +) (I'm using Gson library for this) and insert this list to database (created with GreenDAO). But before inserting I need to sort this list by my objects string field. I'm using Collator class for sorting because this filed may be on different languages. The question is: how to do such a thing using as less memory as possible?

For now I download a String (+String, I've also tryed to use Streams) then parse it (+List) then sorting it (some more objects). I'm doing it in a separate thread but even when it's done the memory not freed. I think this can be solved if I could sort my data when it's already in database (not when selecting it, it's to slow) but I don't know how.

Here is some code.
This is data loading from file. There is the same issue with memory when loading from file too where I'm using InputStream instead of getting JSON string into memory.

```
public static void getEnciclopediaDataFromFile() {
    mRequestStates.put("enc", true);

    try {
        EncyclopediaParser parser = new EncyclopediaParser(ResourceManager.getResourceManager().loadFile("enc_data"),
                                                           ResourceManager.getResourceManager().loadFile("enc_data"),
                                                           1361531132);
        parser.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mRequestStates.put("enc", false);
        EventBus.getDefault().post(EVENT_ENCYCLOPEDIA_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
    }
}
```

Here is parser Thread. There are two constructors - one for loading from web (string param) another for loading from file (InputStream param).

```
    private static class EncyclopediaParser extends Thread {
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Fields
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private String mJsonData;
    private Reader mTitlesReader;
    private Reader mContentReader;
    private long mUpdateTime;

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Constructor
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public EncyclopediaParser(String jsonData, long updateTime) {
        mJsonData = jsonData;
        mUpdateTime = updateTime;
        this.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);
    }

    public EncyclopediaParser(Reader titlesReader, Reader contentReader, long updateTime) {
        mTitlesReader = titlesReader;
        mContentReader = contentReader;
        mUpdateTime = updateTime;
        this.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    // Methods
    //
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Type type;

        try {
            List<ArticleContent> content = null;
            type = new TypeToken<Collection<ArticleContent>>(){}.getType();
            if(mContentReader == null)
                content = new Gson().fromJson(mJsonData, type);
            else
                content = new Gson().fromJson(mContentReader, type);

            List<ArticleTitle> titles = null;
            type = new TypeToken<Collection<ArticleTitle>>(){}.getType();
            if(mTitlesReader == null)
                titles = new Gson().fromJson(mJsonData, type);
            else
                titles = new Gson().fromJson(mTitlesReader, type);

            for(ArticleTitle title : titles)
                title.setTitle(title.getTitle().trim());

            TitlesComparator titlesComparator = new TitlesComparator();
            Collections.sort(titles, titlesComparator);
            for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); ++i)   //sorting enc data
                titles.get(i).setOrderValue((long)i);

            //create sections data
            Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
            collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
            ArrayList<String> sectionNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Integer> sectionIndexesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            String prevLetter = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < titles.size(); ++i) {
                if(titles.get(i).getTitle().length() > 0){
                    if(!Character.isLetter(titles.get(i).getTitle().charAt(0))) {
                        if( !sectionNamesList.contains("#")) {
                            sectionNamesList.add("#");
                            sectionIndexesList.add(i);
                        }
                    }
                    else if(collator.compare(titles.get(i).getTitle().substring(0, 1), prevLetter) > 0) {
                        sectionNamesList.add(titles.get(i).getTitle().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(Locale.GERMAN));
                        sectionIndexesList.add(i);
                    }
                    prevLetter = titles.get(i).getTitle().substring(0, 1);
                }
            }
            String[] sectionNames = new String[sectionNamesList.size()]; //use lists instead
            Integer[] sectionIndexes = new Integer[sectionIndexesList.size()];
            sectionNamesList.toArray(sectionNames);
            sectionIndexesList.toArray(sectionIndexes);
            AppData.setSectionIndexes(Utils.convertIntegers(sectionIndexes));
            AppData.setSectionNames(sectionNames);

            GreenDAO.getGreenDAO().insertArticles(titles, content);
            AppData.setEncyclopediaUpdateTime(mUpdateTime);
            mRequestStates.put("enc", false);
            if(mTitlesReader != null)
                mTitlesReader.close();
            if(mContentReader != null)
                mContentReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Server", e.toString());
        } finally {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(EVENT_ENCYCLOPEDIA_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        }
    }
}
```

All GreenDAO objects are static. Parsing is done only on the first launch (from file) and by "update" button click (from web). I've noticed that even if I'll relaunch my app after initial (from file) parsing is done it'll be using as much memory as after parsing is done for the first time.

Comment: Do you really have to sort the strings before inserting them in the database?  Sorting is something that databases are designed for, and may well outperform anything that you could do.  As long as your database tables have indexes on the appropriate columns then it should be fine.

Comment: I lied to you. I'm using sorting when selecting data from db. But I need to presort it to set sorting indexes (since SQL alphabetic sort is now what I need). And also to define section indexes for fast scroll. I'm updating my listview very often, so I need to predefine section indexes cause calculation of them in adapter constructor makes a large delay. But maybe I can save some memory another way? I noticed that after thread completes it's job used memory not getting freed. Maybe I need to destroy a thread object in some way? I really don't want to use largeHeap.

Comment: You ask how to do this with least memory and mention that the memory is not getting released.  That sounds like a core problem, but not enough info to help with it.  Ultimately, a JSON string with 10K+ objects is a big memory hog unless you break it into smaller chunks.  Do you have access to the server code?

Comment: Not directly. JSON string is about 6 mb. But event it will be smaller I still need to get them all together for sorting and getting sort indexes for database.